# Why can't Yarn install Angular 2's scoped packages (e.g. @angular/common)?

Tags: angular, npm, yarnpkg

For most of my projects I have successfully moved from npm to Yarn. However my Angular 2 projects are resulting in an error:

```sh
$ yarn add  "@angular/common"
yarn add v0.17.8
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
error Couldn't find package "@angular/common" on the "npm" registry.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
```

Even when using one of the quickstarts available from Angular:

```sh
$ git clone https://github.com/angular/quickstart.git quickstart && cd quickstart
…
$ yarn install
yarn install v0.17.8
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
error Couldn't find package "@types/node" on the "npm" registry.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

Am I missing something obvious? I am not seeing any other posts anywhere with this problem, so it might be an environment problem?

```sh
$ yarn versions
yarn versions v0.17.8
{ yarn: '0.17.8',
  'angular-quickstart': '1.0.0',
  http_parser: '2.7.0',
  node: '6.9.1',
  v8: '5.1.281.84',
  uv: '1.9.1',
  zlib: '1.2.8',
  ares: '1.10.1-DEV',
  icu: '57.1',
  modules: '48',
  openssl: '1.0.2j' }
Done in 0.06s.
```

(I'm running on linux/f25)

I have the feeling it is about the @-symbol in the scoped package names?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce using v0.17.8 on Ubuntu 16.10. Try cleaning your Yarn cache (`yarn cache clean`) and rerunning. Also, I take it that other packages that aren't scoped (with the @) work fine? It might also be helpful to test if `npm install @angular/common` works fine to rule out any network issues.

Comment: `npm install @angular/common` works fine, as does `npm install` on for example the quickstart. Just noticed the error with the quickstart above is on `"@types/node"` (before it was on `@angular/forms`). Seems to be really something wrong with the @ on my install?

Comment: That seems really odd. [This bug](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/1260) seems similar - are you using a proxy?

Comment: No proxy. I am using nvm might that interfere.

Comment: It's a shame the [`--verbose` flag isn't implemented yet](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/763); it would have helped with seeing the network requests. I would say the best solution is to file a bug report for now.

Comment: Seems to be the same as  https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/620  (i've added a comment over there)

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a bug in yarn that treats a URL with an at-sign as a url requiring authentication. It then uses the `_auth` configuration to add an auth header. (I had a `_auth' npm config)

The following solved it for now (work around until this gets fixed):

`$ npm config delete _auth`

See also https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/2030